# Python Bluetooth Message Lost?

Tags: python, bluetooth, communication, android-bluetooth

In my IOT project my control panel android app is getting connected to the bluetooth socket running in python app using RFCOMM . This is my init code for bluetooth socket server

```
self.server_sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
self.server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
self.server_sock.listen(1)
self.port = self.server_sock.getsockname()[1]
self.uuid = "94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"
advertise_service( self.server_sock, "SampleServer",
service_id = self.uuid,
service_classes = [ self.uuid, SERIAL_PORT_CLASS ],
profiles = [ SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ], 
               #protocols = [ OBEX_UUID ] 
                )
self.connected_client = None
```

And once a client is connected i am sending the initial values to the app but sometimes one or two message is lost. I am sending the message as follows

```
print("Waiting for connection on RFCOMM channel %d" % self.port)
client_sock, client_info = self.server_sock.accept()
self.connected_client = client_sock
print("Accepted connection from ", client_info)
init_connection(10,"03:00", 0, 0,"Temperature 80degrees","Temperature 30degress");
set_color("S1","#FF0000");
set_color("S2","#FF0000");
set_flashing("S1", True);
set_flashing("S2", True);
```

Last five lines are sending message to the bluetooth socket some times one or two messages are lost